# How to capitalize a text that is written in uppercase?

Tags: jquery, css, styles

I have a text that is written in uppercase. Example:

```
THIS IS UPPERCASE
```

What I want is to make it look like this (capitalize it):

```
This Is Uppercase
```

I just found out I cannot do it with CSS since text-transform: capitalize only works on the first letter, so the output is still:

```
THIS IS UPPERCASE
```

Is there any way with jquery to achieve this effect?

EDIT:

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="badge">
<div class="participant">NAME SURNAME</div>
</div>
```

NAME and SURNAME are **dynamic** variables, but some of the data is written in UPPERCASE, some is written in lowercase and some is written in Capitalize. I just want to uniform the names with Capitalize, possibly including the javascript in my html file, but I have trouble capitalizing strings written in uppercase.

Comment: I took a look at the other question and it does not solve my issue.

Comment: You asked for jQuere, here you go: var makeLowerCase = function() { jQuery( this ).text( jQuery( this ).text().toLowerCase() ); }; jQuery( '.participant' ).each( makeLowerCase ); I don't know how you 'dynamically set your value. But you need to add the makeLowerCase function every time you change. E.g. jQuery( '.participant' ).text( 'bRUCE WAYNE').each( makeLowerCase );

Comment: Of course you need the css <style> .participant{ text-transform: capitalize; } </style>

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function capitalize(str){
        var val = str,
        substr = val.split(' '),
        returnVal = [];

        substr.forEach(function(val){
            returnVal.push(val.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+val.slice(1));
        });

    return returnVal.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: I tried including this javascript in my html but it does not work..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `CSS` or `CSS3` will not be helpful here, you can achieve it in `JavaScript`.

You can do it this way :

```
window.onload = function(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("every-word")
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\\b([a-z])([a-z]+)?\\b/gim, "<span class='first-letter'>$1</span>$2")
  }
}
```

Your HTML will be :

```
<style>
  .first-letter {
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
</style>
<p class="every-word">THIS IS UPPERCASE</p>
```

This will give you output :

```
This Is Uppercase
```

Comment: I tried this:

`<script>

window.onload = function(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("participant")
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\\b([a-z])([a-z]+)?\\b/gim, "<span class='first-letter'>$1</span>$2")
  }
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
 
  .first-letter {
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }

</style>

<div class="badge">
<div class="participant">NAME SURNAME</div>

</div>`

but it does not work. The javascript does not create the span..

Comment: Are you changing your name after page gets loaded ? Or they are added in that place during page load ?

Comment: they were added during the page load with server request .. but I couldn't solve this in time and now it does not matter anymore. superficial and incompetent moderator. it was NOT a duplicate and it did NOT have the answer in that other question.

Comment: You can move this code in a method and call this method when your text is loaded and then this code will format your text data.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = "THIS IS UPPERCASE";

const tc = str.replace(/(\w)+/g, w =>
  w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1).toLowerCase()
);

console.log( tc )
```